# How to align Carto logo

Tags: carto

I'm using Carto Mobile in an Android app and I wonder how could I align the Carto logo on a corner that I choose, instead of having it randomly displayed and interfere with map controls I'm displaying over the map.

Usually it appears in the bottom left corner, and I have a scale bar over there. When it gets displayed there, I cannot see the scale bar correctly. I'd prefer the Carto logo to always be in the bottom right corner, since I have nothing over there.

Aside from that, I guess that if I get to pay for Carto, the logo could be removed, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the commercial license the logo stays to one place (lower-left corner), but cannot be completely removed. This is similar to other map SDK-s like google etc. With no license/evaluation mode the logo is "jumping around" because some creative developers have tried to do dirty tricks to overlap logo in certain place.

Comment: Alright, then I'm good to go, since I do have the commercial license, although I don't use it for the debug APK (it has different package name and I don't find it useful to have an unused license). If I cannot make the logo to appear in a set corner, then I'll just move the ScaleBar to the bottom right. However, I think it could be useful if you allow developers to display it in the corner we decide to. Thanks!